# Having issues with eager loading linq

Tags: linq, eager-loading

My error is:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'

on this line:

```
 return ((IEntityWithRelationships)(this)).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<IgnoreList>("AsanaDataModel.FK_Ignore_Tasks", "IgnoreList").Value;
```

I have two tables:

```
Task (1:0 or 1)
IgnoreList
```

My linq code looks like this:

```
        using (var context = new AsanaDataEntities())
        {
            var query = from t in context.Tasks.Include("IgnoreList")
                        join i in context.IgnoreLists on t.Gid equals i.Gid into jn
                        select t;

            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} tasks.", query.Count());
            if (query.Any())
            {
                taskListView.DataSource = query;
            }
        }
```

I am using query for a datasource for BrightIdeasSoftware's FastDataListView. It needs the have the query fully loaded because it is out of context. IF I do not try to use any values from IgnoreList in the FastDataListView then everything works well.

This is happening any time FastDataListView is trying to access an IgnoreList record in Task.

I am expecting the addition of

```
.Include("IgnoreList")
```

in my query will eagerly load all the existing records for IgnoreList before it is out of context.

Even if I try:

```
var temp = query.ToList<AsanaDataModel.Task>();
```

Directly after my query I still get the same error.
What am I not understanding or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It was my query. My query needed to be:

```
var query = from t in context.Tasks.Include("IgnoreList")
                        select t;
```